# Do not call the delegate method of CKRadialMenu

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use CKRadialMenu library. There is a method

```
- (void) addPopoutView: (UIView *) popoutView withIndentifier: (NSString *) identifier
```

I pass a image view like this..

```
UIImageView *imgForFood2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"food-icon-img 40.png"]];
[_radialView addPopoutView:imgForFood2 withIndentifier:@"ONE"];
```

In the output the image will add but when i try to click this popOutView its delegate method does not fire.
Here is the delegate method

```
-(void)radialMenu:(CKRadialMenu *)radialMenu didSelectPopoutWithIndentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to enable the user Interaction on Imageview.

```
UIImageView *imgForFood2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"food-icon-img 40.png"]];

[imgForFood2 setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
[radialView addPopoutView:imgForFood2 withIndentifier:@"ONE"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIImageView *imgForFood2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"food-icon-img 40.png"]];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
[view addSubview:imgForFood2];
[radialView addPopoutView:view withIndentifier:@"ONE"];
```